# Accessing json object values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am trying to build a WebApp which consumes REST API's with Flask.

I am getting my JSON object back successfully from my API but I am unable to display it in the HTML UI.

Consider I am trying to print userid from the JSON file, I am getting the error part only.

Can someone please point me out what is going wrong :

Here is my JSON Object which returns:
[image]

Here is my JS file:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  $('#try-again').hide();

  // on form submission ...
  $('form').on('submit', function() {

    console.log("the form has beeen submitted");

    // grab values
    valueOne = $('input[name="location"]').val();
    
    console.log(valueOne)

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/",
      data : { 'first': valueOne},
      success: function(result) {
        if (!$.isEmptyObject({result})) {
   $('input').hide();
   $('#try-again').show();
   $('#result').html(result.userid[0])
  $(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  $('#try-again').hide();

  // on form submission ...
  $('form').on('submit', function() {

    console.log("the form has beeen submitted");

    // grab values
    valueOne = $('input[name="location"]').val();
    
    console.log(valueOne)

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/",
      data : { 'first': valueOne},
      success: function(result) {
        if (!$.isEmptyObject({result})) {
   $('input').hide();
   $('#try-again').show();
   $('#result').html(result.userid)
   $('#result').html('result.userid')
        
        } else {
    $('#result').html('Something went terribly wrong! Please try again.')
    
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    });

  });

  $('#try-again').on('click', function(){
    $('input').val('').show();
    $('#try-again').hide();
    $('#result').html('');
  });

});
        
        } else {
    $('#result').html('Something went terribly wrong! Please try again.')
    
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    });

  });

  $('#try-again').on('click', function(){
    $('input').val('').show();
    $('#try-again').hide();
    $('#result').html('');
  });

});
```

My JSON DATA:

```
 [{"case": 2005608875, 
"filepath": "/x/eng/cs-data/latx/dev/20150510_uploads/wilp/perfstat_20150415_001256/node/10.95.172.19/output.data", 
"datatype": "perf8", 
"perfdateend": "2015-04-15T02:15:37-04:00", 
"userid": "wilp", 
"filename": "perfstat_20150415_001256.zip", 
"version": "v8.1 ", 
"perfdate": "2015-04-15T01:14:24-04:00"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here, and none of them have anything to do with Flask.

You check the `length` of the returned JSON object. However, in JS objects do not have a length property, so `result.length` returns `undefined` which is not greater than 0.

Since you are using jQuery, you can use its `isEmptyObject` function to check that your object is not empty.

Also, inside that if statement you are inserting the literal string `'result.userid'` into your HTML, instead of the actual userid value of the returned JSON.

```
   if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
      ...
      $('#result').html(result.userid)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on isEmptyObject I changed it.

But I still cannot print the value.

I have updated the code in main question.
Can you please have a look?

Comment: Your JSON data snippet doesn't match the screenshot for the Chrome tools. Maybe you should post your Flask code after all.